# Saving data.frames over a loop from a namelist in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, save

I'm trying to save some data.frames and tables with a loop. I thought, that it will be easier if I put all the names of the data.frames in a list and call the list later in the for-loop. But I really don't get it. The namelist works for the filename, but I can not get the real dataframe from the namelist. I get always an error message...

That is my code at the moment:

```r
ListTablesCharacter <- c("ResultsConditionDeltaFaceMean","ResultsConditionResponseTimeMean","ResultsManipulationDeltaFaceMean", ... ,"VPNCondition")

for (i in 1:length(ListTablesCharacter)){

  save(get(ListTablesCharacter[i]), file=paste(ListTablesCharacter[i],".rda", sep =""))
  write.csv(get(ListTablesCharacter[i]), file=paste(ListTablesCharacter[i],".csv", sep =""))
}
```

And this is the error message I get at the moment.

```r
Error in save(get(ListTablesCharacter[ii]), file = paste(ListTablesCharacter[ii],  : 
  Object ‘get(ListTablesCharacter[ii])’ not found
```

I believe that the second part, after file = works.

Is there a way to get the save-command over this approach?

It should work like this.

```r
save(ResultsConditionDeltaFaceMean, file=paste("ResultsConditionDeltaFaceMean",".rda", sep =""))
write.csv(ResultsConditionDeltaFaceMean, file=paste("ResultsConditionDeltaFaceMean",".csv", sep =""))

save(ResultsConditionResponseTimeMean, file=paste("ResultsConditionResponseTimeMean",".rda", sep =""))
write.csv(ResultsConditionResponseTimeMean, file=paste("ResultsConditionResponseTimeMean",".csv", sep =""))
#etc.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `save` can take the variable *name* directly, try `save(list = ListTablesCharacter[i], file=paste(ListTablesCharacter[i],".rda", sep =""))`. (Suggestion: if you're saving one object per `.rda` file, you might consider using `saveRDS` instead ... using `save` will load the object named that into the target environment, and the loading user will need to rename it if they want it anywhere else, while they could alternatively do `newvarname <- readRDS("../path/to/foo.rds")` instead if previously saved with `readRDS`. The two save-types are not compatible.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to try your suggestion. Do you also have one for write.csv?

Comment: Nope, that needs data itself, so lacking other constructs, `get(...)` is useful there. I do find it odd that your loop is `for (i in...)` but your error references `[ii]` (which is not anywhere else in your sample code). While this might be a copy/paste thing, it could mean any number of things. Unfortunately, we can't really help if the code we see here is that-different from the real code.

Comment: Thank you, this was a copy/paste error. In the script, it was only with [i]. Well, I tried some things and ended up just hardcoding it. I know shame... but after a while, I lost focus.